# stuck transaction in ride the lightning on chain transaction

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, lightning-network-daemon

[image]

This transaction was send in ride the lighting on chain transaction,  it has zero confirmation, how do I send it out, or cancel the transaction?

Comment: Hi cakephp_dev1, what Lightning Node implementation is your RTL connected to?

Comment: this, i think it is the LND implementation, try to search around the setting in RTL, but it did not indicates, but i remember it is LND

Comment: yes, just saw the setting it is lnd, thanks